# Assign value to the symbol returned by function

Tags: evaluation, assignment

Ok, so here is example code:

```
Clear[p, flag, k];
p = 2;
k = 1;
flag = True;
If[flag, p, k] = 0;
p
```

After that I get the message

```
Set::write: Tag If in If[True,p,k] is Protected.
```

And p is still 2 instead of 0.
How can I make the p equal to 0 in this case?

EDIT: My question is general - how to return the symbol from some function, not only If - and be able to change its value later (for example by Set)

EDIT #2: I know that with associations I can do that easily:

```
Clear[p, flag, k];
v = <||>;
v[p] = 2;
v[k] = 1;
flag = True;
v[If[flag, p, k]] = 0;
v[p]
```

I just wish I could the same just on symbols..

Comment: Your are trying to define a value for the function "If", but "If" is protected. "If" can not be on the left side of an assignment.. Even if it were executed, you would then have  "2=0".

Comment: I know but how to assign to p properly then ?

Comment: Or in general, how to return from that if the symbol and then assign value to it?

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you want to do. Perhaps: If[flag,p=0,k=0]

Comment: So i have to write = 0 twice? There is no option to get just the symbol and then assign?

Comment: The above example is simple but if I have to assign same value to one of many symbols, it becomes problematic

Comment: There are ways, but for a one time use, the above is the best. If you really want a solution: SetAttributes[myIf, HoldAll]
myIf[f_, p_, k_] := If[f, p = 0, k = 0]
p = 2;
k = 1;
myIf[flag, p, k];
p

Comment: In the definition you still type twice " =0 ". So it is almost the same in my case. I ask more about generally returning symbols from functions (not only If) and assigning values to them later

Comment: I would even go further and say `If[flag, p, k] = 0;` is trying to be too clever, yet not succeeding in being so.

Answer (score 3):

At first I wasn’t sure how to realize this, but upon seeing m_goldberg’s example with `Set` inside of `If`, it hit me:

```
Clear[p, flag, k];
p = 2;
k = 1;
flag = True;
If[flag, Set[p,#], Set[k,#]]&[0];
p
```

And this, of course, returns `0` if `flag = True` and `2` if `flag = False`.

It might be easier to see it this way:

```
Clear[p, flag, k];
p = 2;
k = 1;
flag = True;
If[flag, p=#, k=#]&[0];
p
```

which also works like the above. You could streamline this a bit more & wrap it into a function, but I think this answers your question & gives it to you in a form that is loose enough for you to modify to your desires! Nothing fancy, just anonymous functions.

Comment: +1 I also had your 2nd example as an afterthought, but when I signed in to update my answer, i was way too late.

Comment: @m_goldberg you could update/expand upon the 1st example you have by having `”=“<>ToString[arg]` and make it a function, where `arg` is `0`, for OP’s case? Maybe that’s a bit less concise though...

Answer (score 1):

Here are two methods that are essentially the same.

```
Clear[p, flag, k];
p = 2;
k = 1;
flag = True;
Evaluate[If[flag, p =.; p, k =.; k]] = 0;
p  {* 0 *}
```

If you want to use a function, maybe this method:

```
Clear[func, p, flag, k];

func[flag_?BooleanQ, str1_String, str2_String] := If[flag,
  Clear[str1]; ToExpression[str1],
  Clear[str2]; ToExpression[str2]]

p = 2;
k = 1;
flag = True;
Evaluate[func[flag, "p", "k"]] = 0;
p  (* 0 *)
```

The salient points are (1) the symbol must be cleared or unset and (2) use `Evaluate` on the left side of the equals sign.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly concise but still silly way to do it.

```
Clear[p, flag, k];
p = 2;
k = 1;
flag = True;
ToExpression[If[flag, "p", "k"] <> "=0"];
p
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

However, I would rather  write

```
Clear[p, flag, k];
p = 2;
k = 1;
flag = True;
If[flag, p = 0, k = 0];
p
```

and, I believe, so would everybody else. it is the standard practice and is both more concise and efficient then any playing games to limit the code to one written `Set` expression.